# 404 error for chrome LibX extension installation link

Tags: google-chrome

I met 404 error when I click the link for the installation of the LibX extension for Google Chrome recently. When I used the google web store to search keyword "libx", it shows that there are no matching results.
I asked several people around and they all met the same issue. Does anyone have any idea of what's going on there and how to fix this problem?